# Coverage in Jest and Enzyme in React aplication

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage, enzyme

I have a React application and I added tests with jest and enzyme. I make a unit test for a react component called `<Duration.jsx />`.
And the coverage shows me all components coverage inside `<Duration.jsx />` and files.scss. Is it normal?

[image]

Comment: if you are asking how to skip analyzing SASS files for test coverage there is dedicated config option for that: [`collectCoverageFrom `](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#collectcoveragefrom-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this depends on how you write your tests. IMHO, the coverage is a by-product of tests. For example, if you use `enzyme` and `shallow(<LayoutMessage />)`, then you are not going to render the children of `LayoutMessage`.

If you render normally using `render(<LayoutMessage />)` then you will also render the children of `LayoutMessage`, increasing the lines that your tests execute.

Here's a sample picture for testing individual component. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using shallow. `const component = shallow(<Duration />);`

Comment: I can't see very clearly your image, but seems your first two lines on the screen says you are running two test files. Can you post the file content on those files?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have two tests but the second one `<Duration.jsx />` is the problem. 
This is my unit test.
`import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Duration from '../../Timer/Duration';

describe('Panel', () => {
  it('Edit product button should render correctly', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Duration />);
    expect(component.instance().isZeroOrEmpty('0')).toBe(true);
  });
});`

Comment: Kool, if you are sure this one is the problem, could you do me a favor? Print out `console.log(component.debug());` after the component is initialized. The reason for that is I want to see if any code has been generated for your children component. It'll be helpful to publish your Duration.jsx file :)

Comment: This is the console output  `<TimeWrapper title="Duration">
        <EmptyTime />
        <Buttons onClickSetTime={[Function]} onBlur={[Function]} className="timer-button-duration" />
      </TimeWrapper>`

Comment: Then according to the doc, https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/debug.html, you shouldn't reach `TimeWrapper`. Make sure you don't have any other reference to `TimeWrapper` just search this keyword in your test files. You shouldn't see any residue in the coverage if no dependency is mentioned.